# How to remove table's borders in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, border

i tried to change color to white, and change border style to dashed.
But I don't know why it kept undoing my setting. How do I set to hide borders? I have 2 tables in a rectangle

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You hide borders by setting the `BorderStyle` property to `None`. Note that you may also need to change this on the cells that are adjacent so that they don't have a border property setting that would put a border along the adjoining edge.

The `BorderStyle` property is not part of the Tablix Properties dialog box, it is on the Properties panel in the Border section (press F4 or menu View-Properties Window if this isn't displayed).

If you click the top left handle of the table to select the entire table you will see this in the Properties panel. You can also set the BorderStyle if you select an individual cell or range of cells.

If you have the View-Toolbars-Report Borders menu option selected, you can also use the BorderStyle dropdown to quickly set common BorderStyle options on the selected report items.

Comment: Where is the border style property, in table properties I dont have this option.

Comment: It is not part of the Tablix Properties dialog box, it is on the Properties panel in the Border section. If you click the top left handle of the table to select the entire table you will see this in the Properties panel (if you don't see the Properties panel, press F4 or use the menu View-Properties Window) and you can also set the BorderStyle if you select an individual cell or range of cells.

Answer (score 10):

The fastest way is the answer of Chris Lätta if you want to do it by table. But if you want to hide the border by textbox you could do it this way.

1. Right click on the textbox that you want to remove the border
2. click Text 'Box Properties'
3. click 'Border'
4. then select 'None' on Presents options.http://prntscr.com/8w7i0k

Comment: I needed to remove all of the borders from all of the tablix cells/textboxes in a report but this single textbox method was going to take a lot of time on a large tablix.  However, I found a shortcut.  I found out you can drag-select either all columns or all rows in the tablix and then press F4 to go to the properties view.  With all rows or columns selected you can then set the Border Style property to "None" for all the selected textboxes instead of having to edit each one individually.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by removing the page header on the report.

Right click anywhere outside of the tablix on the report and you should see a remove page header option.